# Multiple users logged in

Tags: tty, top, who

I'm looking at top and see that there are two users. Using who gives the following:

```
           system boot  2014-12-22 14:15
           run-level 2  2014-12-22 14:15
LOGIN      tty4         2014-12-22 14:15               996 id=4
LOGIN      tty5         2014-12-22 14:15              1001 id=5
LOGIN      tty2         2014-12-22 14:15              1009 id=2
LOGIN      tty3         2014-12-22 14:15              1010 id=3
LOGIN      tty6         2014-12-22 14:15              1014 id=6
LOGIN      tty1         2014-12-22 14:16              3508 id=1
user ?     :0           2014-12-22 14:17   ?          3576 (:0)
user     + pts/0        2014-12-23 11:49   .         18392 (:0)
           pts/8        2014-12-23 11:49                 0 id=/8    term=0 exit=0
```

Why are there two users? I know that the lower user is the one from my terminal (pts). How about the one above that? It's not even a tty, what is that ":0" supposed to signify?

Comment: `:0` is the X display - the GUI.

Comment: What is the output of `w`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:0 is the X11 display, if you have several screens or displays it will list them :0,:1, :2, etc...

:0 is your desktop.

Comment: screens != displays in X. I have two screens, but I still only get :0 and 4 pts.

Answer (score 0):

**:0** means that the user is logged through the **X server**. Thus there are two users because one is logged via terminal and other in the **X server** (**GUI**).

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72177/what-is-pts-0-and-0-0-in-linux-by-type-who-am-i). To summarize it:

First, there are no "two users" - there is one, who is logged in multiple times.

And, as muru said, :0 normally refers to a log in via some graphical interface. Using "w" will tell you which interface logging into your system.